# Elementwise comparison to None with ndarray of object dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
x = np.empty([2], dtype=object)
> array([None, None], dtype=object)

x[0] = 'a'
> array(['a', None], dtype=object)
```

I'm trying to get a boolean array `[False, True]` from this object typed `ndarray` where the object type is `None`.

Things that don't work: `x is None`, `x.isfinite()`, `x == None`, `np.isnan(x)`. The array may be in `n` dimensions, making for loop iterations unpleasant to look at.

Comment: As an aside, you should do your best to avoid working with `dtype=object` arrays. They are essentially stunted Python lists. Perhaps you can try a sized string dtype?

Comment: NumPy also has [MaskedArrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), they might not be totally easy to grasp initially. But especially if you have some "invalid" entries these are much faster than object arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In NumPy 1.12 and earlier, you'll need to explicitly call `numpy.equal` to get a broadcasted equality comparison. Leave a comment, so future readers understand why you're doing it:

```
# Comparisons to None with == don't broadcast (yet, as of NumPy 1.12).
# We need to use numpy.equal explicitly.
numpy.equal(x, None)
```

In NumPy 1.13 and later, [`x == None` will give you a broadcasted equality comparison](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#futurewarning-to-changed-behavior), but you can still use `numpy.equal(x, None)` if you want backward compatibility with earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap `None` in a `list` or `array` to force element-wise comparisons:

```
>>> x == [None]
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> x == np.array([None])
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few possible ways to do that is -

```
x < 0
x!='a'
```

> array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

Comment: x < 0 was a surprise, neat shortcut. x!='a' of course only works for 'a', but good point if that's the goal. Thanks!

Comment: The `< 0` approach only works in python-2.x. In Python 3 it will throw an exception. Also the return seems wrong - I get `array([False,  True], dtype=bool)` for the `x != 'a'` comparison.